# What are the impacts of changing SSL certificate in Application Server

Tags: ssl-certificate

We have Application Server hosted a Web Site Portal in SharePoint 2007 and a SilverLight Application as subsite. We need to change the SSL Certificate of the server. What are the potential impacts on changing the SSL certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you sign the certificate using a known CA (say VeriSign, Thwate), there should be no impact. The procedure should be seamless.

Comment: If not VeriSign, like we have this Active Directory Certificate Service. Does it still have impacts?

Comment: If its internal to your company and is trusted with all the browsers in your organization, you should be good. How is the current SSL cert signed ?

Comment: I believed it's internal. Thanks you very much for the reply. This will be of big help to us. By the way, this in connection with the "Heartbleed" bug.